# coreplot - always same plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, core-plot

im working with coreplot the firs time - and got it up and running so far. now i stumbled upon a strange problem.

> > i fear that i missed a vital function or concept of coreplot =)

im implemented:

```
numberofRecords
doubleForPlot
```

and have debugged (especially doubleForPlot) over and over and am 100% sure that doubleforplot actually returns the correct double for the given index.

but: the shown plot is **always** the same. i get a line (screenshot on the bottom of the question).

i tried: 
**debugging** doubleForPlot - it returns the right number
**different data** i tried returning always the same number, expecting to see a constant line, *result: an empty plot*.
**different data** i tried returning some other values (not constant) but then i get the shown screenshots plot all over again.

here is my code:

**IBAction** - calls the data inizalisation and builds the graphview

```
-(IBAction)displayDayBalanceGraph:(id)sender{
if (hasSubView) {

    //[[expenseTable subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self updateView];
    NSLog(@"%@",expenseTable.subviews);
}

else{

    [self initializeMonthArray];

    CPTGraphHostingView *host = [self buildGraphView];

    [expenseTable addSubview:host];

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc ]initWithFrame:host.frame];
    [graph setDelegate:self];


    // CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
    // [graph applyTheme:theme];
    host.hostedGraph = graph;


    CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init ];
    plot.dataSource = self;
    [plot setIdentifier:@"balanceChart"];

    [plot setTitle:@"Balance History"];


    [graph addPlot:plot];


    hasSubView = !hasSubView;
}

}
```

**Create View** - initialises a hosting view with the right size

```
-(CPTGraphHostingView *)buildGraphView{

CPTGraphHostingView *view = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 220)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[self grayColor]];

return view;
}
```

**data initialization** - gets called when an IBAction is hit to show the graph

```
-(void)initializeMonthArray{

[dataHandler updateData];

if (!allMonthExpenses) {
    allMonthExpenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:31];
} 

for (NSMutableArray *temp in allMonthExpenses) {
    [temp removeAllObjects];
}

[allMonthExpenses removeAllObjects];

for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++) {          //fill with 31 empty mutuable arrays
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [allMonthExpenses addObject:tempArray];
}

for (Expense *exp in dataHandler.allMonthExpenses) {
    if (exp.expenseType.boolValue == 0) {
        [[allMonthExpenses objectAtIndex:(exp.day.intValue-1)]addObject:exp];
    }
}
}
```

**doubleForPlot** - returns the right double for an index

```
-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

if (fieldEnum == 0) {

    NSLog(@"Axis: %d and Value: %d",fieldEnum, index+1);
    return (double)(index+1);
}

if (fieldEnum == 1) {

    int dayInt = [dataHandler getDayNumber:[NSDate date]].intValue;
    double total = 0;
    for (Expense *exp in [allMonthExpenses objectAtIndex:index]) {
        total = total + exp.value.doubleValue;
    }

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-(dayInt-(int)index-1)*(60*60*24))];

    double budgetValue = [dataHandler getSpecificBudgetForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-(dayInt-(int)index-1)*(60*60*24))] ];
    total = budgetValue+total;    

    NSLog(@"\n Axis:%d \n Record for Day: %@ \n IndexForPlot: %d \n Value: %.2f \n",fieldEnum, date,index,total);

    return total;
}

else
    return 0;
}
```

**numberOfRecords** - returns the right amount of entries

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{    
return [dataHandler getDayNumber:[NSDate date]].intValue;

}
```

**screenshot** - the plot that is shown no matter what data i enter

[image: le stupid empty plot]

**LOG** - this log is created in the doubleforplot method at the end proving that the right result is returned:

```
NSLog(@"\n Record for Day: %@ \n IndexForPlot: %d \n Value: %.2f \n",date,index,total);
```

out:

```
2012-03-20 10:29:55.834 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
Record for Day: 2012-03-01 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 0 
 Value: 34.35 
2012-03-20 10:29:55.841 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-02 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 1 
 Value: 8.35 
2012-03-20 10:29:55.848 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-03 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 2 
 Value: 35.83 
2012-03-20 10:29:55.856 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-04 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 3 
 Value: -14.89 
2012-03-20 10:29:55.863 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-05 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 4 
 Value: 36.56 
2012-03-20 10:29:55.869 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-06 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 5 
 Value: 8.96 

.... sparing you a lot of other log except the last.

2012-03-20 10:29:55.980 DailyBudget[9493:fb03] 
 Record for Day: 2012-03-20 09:29:55 +0000 
 IndexForPlot: 19 
 Value: 14.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a simple error. Every point in the line drawn in the graph should have x and y values. You  return same value for x and y. You can differentiate it by the value of fieldenum in the method

```
-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

. fieldenum will be zero for CPTScatterPlotFieldX and 1 for CPTScatterPlotFieldY.

Comment: hi - thanks! this explains why it would show a straight line x=y. i changed it (see new code in question) - but now i get an empty plot (see screenshot). so not all the way through yet ;)

Comment: im so used to plotting with matlab that i didnt think about having to set the range manually for a first impression =)
thanks a million! no ill start fighting with labels etc =)